# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory at org.apache.http.conn.ssl

Tags: java, android, android-studio, http-post, httpclient

I'm trying to send http request POST to my goolge form to update my worksheet, but have this error in Android Studio:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
>       at org.apache.http.conn.ssl

At this line: `CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();`

**But in Eclipse it works!!!**

My code is:

```
public class MyClass{
   public static void main(String[] args)
           throws IOException, ServiceException
{

 String fullUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/**key**/formResponse";
 CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
 HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(fullUrl);
 httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 HttpResponse response = null;
 String data = "entry_770028073=" + URLEncoder.encode("ITPOD_pp1")+"&"+"entry_835458425=" + URLEncoder.encode("sr1");
 StringEntity tmp = new StringEntity(data,"UTF-8");
 httpPost.setEntity(tmp);
 try {
     response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);

     if (response != null) {

         String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
     }
 } catch (Exception e) {}

 }
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: if wanna support old http client in Android Studio, add these lines in gradle android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
} , I am not how much this work but this is what given by android developer site.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `common-loggins` [library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) in your project, in Eclipse it has include by default when you create a project